# Installing mod_wsgi for apache VC11 build on windows

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have Apache 2.4 VC11 build and Python 3.4 (Compiled with VC10) installed on my windows x64 PC. I want to install mod_wsgi, but couldn't find any VC11 build for it. I, however, tried to use VC10 build and it's not going through. Is there any incompatibility between Python VC10 and Apache VC11 binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

it explains everything about Windows builds quite clearly.

Python 3.4 requires a VC10 compiler, not VC11.

Loading VC10 Python/mod_wsgi into a VC11 Apache may not work.

You should use VC10 Apache instead to be safe.